# Mule ESB development and production mode

Tags: java, configuration, esb, mule

Looking at the logs it looks like Mule is always starting in Developement Mode,

How do I switch this for Production?

```
**********************************************************************
* Mule ESB and Integration Platform *
* Version: 3.1.0 Build: 20848 *
* MuleSoft, Inc. *
* For more information go to http://www.mulesoft.org *
* *
* Server started: 5/24/11 10:45 AM *
* Server ID: 7159b2cb-85ea-11e0-b218-8777a961ba72 *
* JDK: 1.6.0_23 (mixed mode) *
* OS encoding: UTF-8, Mule encoding: UTF-8 *
* OS: Linux (2.6.18-238.el5, amd64) *
* Host: JAVVM17 (127.0.0.1) *
* Mode: Development *
* *
* Agents Running: *
* JMX Agent *
**********************************************************************
```

EDIT

I found out that the setting comes from  org.mule.util.ServerStartupSplashScreen

```
    // Dev/Production mode
    final boolean productionMode = StartupContext.get().getStartupOptions().containsKey("production");
    header.add("Mode: " + (productionMode ? "Production" : "Development"));
```

This is set in MuleContainer and MuleServer init method, but we do not use those as we are starting mule from servlet listener in Tomcat

I cannot find any real use for it. Does mule use this flag for something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew Perepelytsya
May 27, 2011; 4:15pm
Re: Mule ESB development and production mode
Reply | Threaded | More [Click for more options]   star
Andrew Perepelytsya
7502 posts

Hi Boris,

It's a legacy code, at the moment it doesn't affect things. The only potential use for it in Mule 3 I can think of for now is to disable hot-deployment.

Andrew

http://mule.1045714.n5.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=user_nodes&user=103667